# Nhibernate one-to-one mapping

Tags: nhibernate-mapping

Hello guys I've tried searching for a solution to this problem for a period of time. Couldn't find it.
I have two classes which I will simplify. My problem is that i want a unidirectional one-to-one mapping between Player and Clan. Now I saw examples which have foreign key in ther id. But I don't understand it. This mapping is not producing a column in my Clans table for ClanLeader... Am i missing something? Thank you all for help.

```
public class Clan{
         private Int32 id;

                public virtual Int32 Id
                {
                    get { return id; }
                    set { id = value; }
                }

            private string name;

            public virtual string Name
                {
                    get { return name; }
                    set { name = value; }
                }

                private Player clanLeader;

                public virtual Player ClanLeader
                {
                    get { return clanLeader; }
                    set { clanLeader = value; }
                }
    }
```

---

Then we have mapping for Clan:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="NHibernateSQLite"
                   namespace="NHibernateSQLite" >

  <class name="GamingOrganizerDomainModel.Clan, GamingOrganizerDomainModel" table="Clans"  lazy="false">

    <id name="id" access="field" column="Clan_ID" type="Int32">
      <generator class="native"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="Name"  column="Clan_Name" unique-key="ClanNameConstraint" type="String"/>


    <one-to-one name="ClanLeader" class="GamingOrganizerDomainModel.Player, GamingOrganizerDomainModel" />

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Next is the class Player:

```
public class Player{
private Int32 id;

                public virtual Int32 Id
                {
                    get { return id; }
                    set { id = value; }
                }

            private string nickname;

            public virtual string Nickname
                {
                    get { return name; }
                    set { name = value; }
                }

}
```

And mapping for Player:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="NHibernateSQLite"
                   namespace="NHibernateSQLite" >

  <class name="GamingOrganizerDomainModel.Player, GamingOrganizerDomainModel" table="Players"  lazy="false">

    <id name="id" column="Player_ID" access="field" type="Int32">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <property name="nickname" access="field" column="Nickname"/>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unidirectional one to one relation should be mapped as "many-to-one" element. "one-to-one" is used for bidirectional one to one. See this [post](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2010/03/conform-mapping-one-to-one.html) for more details. Howerver there are ConfORM mappings as well the article is crystal clear.

You need make only one change in your Clan mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="GamingOrganizerDomainModel"
                   namespace="GamingOrganizerDomainModel" >

    <class name="Clan" table="Clans"  lazy="false">
        <id name="id" access="field" column="Clan_ID" type="Int32">
            <generator class="native"></generator>
        </id>
        <property name="Name"  column="Clan_Name" unique-key="ClanNameConstraint" type="String"/>

        <many-to-one name="ClanLeader" class="Player" />
    </class>
```

You do not need to write assembly qualified class name in the mapping. Assembly and namespace attributes of hibernate-mapping element specify default namespace and assembly where NH tries to find specific class.

Comment: I am glad that this answer has helped. Please mark this qustion as answered:).